# onkeydown not working to change focus in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, keylistener

Im trying to set focus to another from element using javascript in aspx file but it sets for a moment then the form reloads and focus is lost,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sname" runat="server"  CssClass="input" Width="280px" onkeyup="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('fname').focus();"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is the in detail code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sname" runat="server"  CssClass="input" Width="280px" onkeyup="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('fname').focus();"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server"  CssClass="input" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: dont know why the whole form reloads, is it beacuse of postBack or something

Comment: Can we get more code, like the element "fname" and any script that might be running on this page?

Comment: Does this page have a PageLoad event?  If so, does that event get hit after you click on the "sname" text box?

Comment: @MatthewJones im not using any pageLoad event....this is the only script im using till now on this page

Answer (score 0):

The getElementById method won't match "fname" because WebForms changes the names of the asp controls.  You'll need to change the onkeyup call to this:

```
onkeyup="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('<%=fname.ClientID %>').focus();"
```

Comment: yes i do have "fname", for less then a second the focus sets on "fname" and then lost